# MULTIPOLYGON to GEOM

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have this kind of MultiPolygon. How can I convert it to a geom?
When I use UPDATE table SET geom = ST_GeomFromText('WKT'), I have an error:

ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry

HINT:  "WK" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry

```
WKT
MULTIPOLYGON (((24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543,24.0538007353528 37.7379487552645,24.0536236884047 37.7380046312008,24.0535794162991 37.7380077309477,24.0535382978588 37.7379758484951,24.0534338058209 37.7380279295364,24.0534348887244 37.7380896641314,24.053460740598 37.7381057377936,24.0534867036416 37.7381190093452,24.0535498820047 37.7381290046238,24.053633022553 37.7381254748393,24.0537206363065 37.7380982153644,24.0538080832798 37.7380751589808,24.0538873759795 37.7380350692302,24.0539348015795 37.7379969871668,24.0539640433116 37.7379275964686,24.0539663216762 37.7378701532806,24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ST_GeomFromText ('MULTIPOLYGON (24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543,
    24.0538007353528 37.7379487552645,
    24.0536236884047 37.7380046312008,
    24.0535794162991 37.7380077309477,
    24.0535382978588 37.7379758484951,
    24.0534338058209 37.7380279295364,
    24.0534348887244 37.7380896641314,
    24.053460740598 37.7381057377936,
    24.0534867036416 37.7381190093452,
    24.0535498820047 37.7381290046238,
    24.053633022553 37.7381254748393,
    24.0537206363065 37.7380982153644,
    24.0538080832798 37.7380751589808,
    24.0538873759795 37.7380350692302,
    24.0539348015795 37.7379969871668,
    24.0539640433116 37.7379275964686,
    24.0539663216762 37.7378701532806,
    24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543)');
```

or

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
'MULTIPOLYGON ((
    (24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543,
    24.0538007353528 37.7379487552645,
    24.0536236884047 37.7380046312008,
    24.0535794162991 37.7380077309477,
    24.0535382978588 37.7379758484951,
    24.0534338058209 37.7380279295364,
    24.0534348887244 37.7380896641314,
    24.053460740598 37.7381057377936,
    24.0534867036416 37.7381190093452,
    24.0535498820047 37.7381290046238,
    24.053633022553 37.7381254748393,
    24.0537206363065 37.7380982153644,
    24.0538080832798 37.7380751589808,
    24.0538873759795 37.7380350692302,
    24.0539348015795 37.7379969871668,
    24.0539640433116 37.7379275964686,
    24.0539663216762 37.7378701532806,
    24.0538073758627 37.7378703845543)))', 4326);
```

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: Thanks but I keep having the ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry

Comment: That's werid. Can you do other simple example in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html  in your db?